# HttpWebRequest using POST method

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I know about passing string parameters to `HttpWebRequest` using the POST method. How can I pass a string[] array to `HttpWebRequest`? Is it possible to pass an array as a parameter to `HttpWebRequest` using the POST method?

Using the GET method, I can pass an array of strings in QueryString to `HttpWebRequest`, but for the POST method is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx) method to write the request data.

Comment: yes we can do this for posting a string parameter by getting the Byte array and write it in stream But I need to pass string[] "Array" parameter to get Posted.